# Rules/Notions explaining/regulating seemingly non complementary combinations of inflections/conjugations/tenses

Tags: japanese, tense, relative-clauses

**Note:**

My original question was

[Sentences with strange/Incorrect(from English point of view) [Time conjunctive][Conclusive verb form] combinations and aspects/nuances reflected?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/79918/how-can-i-combine-time-markers-with-different-verb-tenses)

---

---

Below is what I found so far. What is the difference between the three notions? And are there other notions that cover the problem of 'weird-looking' mix of tenses?

> **1) Aspect-Tense Notion:**
> [How can this sentence using 次 be in the past tense?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/16158/how-can-this-sentence-using-%e6%ac%a1-be-in-the-past-tense/16159#comment130566_16159)

> **2) Relative-Non relative tense Notion**
> [住んでいた時 or 住んでいる時](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/77753/%e4%bd%8f%e3%82%93%e3%81%a7%e3%81%84%e3%81%9f%e6%99%82-or-%e4%bd%8f%e3%82%93%e3%81%a7%e3%81%84%e3%82%8b%e6%99%82)

> **3) Perfective-Imperfective Notion**
> https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Japanese_verb_conjugation#Perfective

---

---

Edit:

**4) Order of events in one's mind Notion:** Another notion I found in the **Answer** of:
[Usage of した時 vs. している時?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/77217/usage-of-%e3%81%97%e3%81%9f%e6%99%82-vs-%e3%81%97%e3%81%a6%e3%81%84%e3%82%8b%e6%99%82)

Comment: Sorry, but I can't understand what you're asking. Aspect (including perfective/imperfective) is not part of tense.

Comment: @curiousdannii My bad, I meant verb inflections (if tenses is wrong).